# Android studio doesn't show google maps

Tags: android, maps, api-key

I am trying to display google maps on my app using Android Studio but even when I run just the default project of google maps it doesn't want to show the map. I have an API key and the necessary dependencies. I have inserted the meta-data into the manifest, but I still can't get a map on my app. 
Any help please?

Comment: Run through USB debugging or Install .APK in device.

Comment: please share some Log detail.

Answer (score 1):

1- In Android Studio project, you have to insert:

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="API_KEY GOES HERE"/>
```

2- In your Google Developer Console project you have to add certificate fingerprint and your application id.

Example:

```
BB:0D:AC:74:D3:21:E1:43:67:71:9B:62:91:AF:A1:66:6E:44:5D:75;com.example.android.mapexample
```

Explained in details in the following Google guide (Expand this part: `Displaying the release certificate fingerprint`):

[Getting Started | Google Maps Android API | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start)